# Is there a method annotation to indicate that it matches a specified functional interface?

Tags: methods, groovy, compiler-errors, annotations, functional-interface

I'm looking for a way to annotate methods to indicate that they match some specified functional interface, and how to specify that some parameter requiring a method reference only accepts methods with that annotation.

Motivation: I'm looking to be able to check that the signatures of the method matches the accepted functional interface at compile-time rather than at run-time, when the method is called with incorrect arguments. (None of the methods are private, and all are able to be marked as final with no undesired side-effects)

Comment: @groovy.transform.CompileStatic

Comment: I think this what I'm looking for, thanks.